# Multiples Hadoop FileSystem instances

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a class (I removes try/catch for readability):

```
public class HadoopFileSystem {

    private FileSystem m_fileSystem = null;

    public HadoopFileSystem() {
        Configuration l_configuration = new Configuration();
        l_configuration .set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9100");
        l_configuration .set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:9101");

        m_fileSystem = FileSystem.get(l_configuration );

    }

    public void close() {
        m_fileSystem.close();
    }

    public void createFile(String a_pathDFS) {
        m_fileSystem.create(new Path(a_pathDFS));
    }

}
```

In my program, I a first `HadoopFileSysem` object, **I don't close it**.

Then I create a second `HadoopFileSysem` object, and I close it.

Finally, when I want to use a function on `m_fileSystem` in my first object, I have the error : `java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed`

But I did'nt close it !

Here's a little code to illustrate my problem :

```
HadoopFileSystem h1 = new HadoopFileSystem();
HadoopFileSystem h2 = new HadoopFileSystem();

if(h1 == h2)
    System.out.println("=="); // No print
if(h1.equals(h2))
    System.out.println("equals"); // No print

h2.close();
h1.createFile("test.test"); // ERROR : java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
h1.close();
```

Why ?

Comment: Can you please post the code where you create your HadoopFileSystems and where you call your function? This class is unlikely to contain the errors that you're looking for

Comment: I just edited with my example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`m_fileSystem = FileSystem.get(l_configuration );` is a static call even if you have two different objects created. You need to find a way to **not** make this call static for two different objects.

Try this out to do away with the problem,

```
conf.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", true);
```

Comment: Thanks JtheRocker, that explains everything. Would you have an idea to make it non static ?

Comment: Let me get back to you. I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: Just perfect. Made my day.

Comment: No problem :) for any further problem, look at this: https://github.com/shot/hadoop-source-reading/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java

Comment: Is calling FileSystem.newInstance(...) also a solution?

Comment: @snooze92: I think yes, in the Hadoop 2 API :).  I answered this for versions below that probably.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object based on a configuration which is hard-coded. This basically means that you're creating 2 identical objects. Because these objects are identical, the JVM will reference to the same object. So h1 and h2 are referencing the same object.

The reason for this is because you're getting an existing instance of an object based on a configuration file. If the configuration is different for h1 and h2, it will not be the same instance anymore.

Comment: I tested with : `if(h1 == h2) System.out.println("==");
  if(h1.equals(h2)) System.out.println("equals");` and I have no "print" ?

Comment: @Apaachee can you remove the h2.close(); and run it again? Do you still get the error if you don't do the close on h2 first?

Comment: No I do not get the error again. the `h2.close()` closes me the `h1`  too. How can I solve my problem ? And why `==` returns nothing ?

Comment: I'll update my answer with another suggestion for fixing your problem. Does that work for you? If it doesn't, then I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: It does'nt fix my problem, FileSystem.close() closes all the instances of FileSystem. Thank you anyway :(

Comment: @Apaachee http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/33042 maybe you can get some info from that link. Good luck, sorry I couldn't help you more

Comment: Thanks for all JREN, this is an early resolution

Comment: @Apaachee, I updated my answer one last time to try and explain why the code works the way it does for you. I just don't know a direct solution for your problem (unless you can change the configuration ofcourse)