# Apache Pig- ERROR 6007: "Unable to check name" message

Tags: java, hbase, apache-pig

Environment: hadoop 1.0.3, hbase 0.94.1, pig 0.11.1

I am running a pig script in Java program, I get the following error sometimes but not all the time. What the program does is it loads a file from hdfs, do some transformation and store it into hbase.  My program is multi-threaded. And I've already made PigServer thread-safe and  I have "/user/root" directory created in hdfs. Here is the snippet of the program and the exception I've got.  Please advise.

```
pigServer = PigFactory.getServer();
URL path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cfg/concatall.py");  
LOG.info("CDNResolve2Hbase: reading concatall.py file from " + path.toString());
pigServer.getPigContext().getProperties().setProperty(PigContext.JOB_NAME,
"CDNResolve2Hbase");
pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputPath + "' using PigStorage('\t') as     (ip:chararray, do:chararray, cn:chararray, cdn:chararray, firsttime:chararray,     updatetime:chararray);");
pigServer.registerCode(path.toString(),"jython","myfunc");
pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate myfunc.concatall('"+ extractTimestamp (inputPath)+"',ip,do,cn), cdn, SUBSTRING(firsttime,0,8);");
outputTable = "hbase://" + outputTable;
ExecJob job = pigServer.store  ("B",outputTable,"org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('d:cdn d:dtime')");
```

and my PigFactory has the following code

```
private static ThreadLocal<PigServer> pigServer = new ThreadLocal<PigServer>();
public static synchronized PigServer getServer() {
if (pigServer.get() == null) {
try
{ printClassPath(); Properties prop = SystemUtils.getCfg(); pigServer.set(new PigServer    (ExecType.MAPREDUCE, prop)); return pigServer.get(); }
catch (Exception e)
{ LOG.error("error in starting PigServer:", e); return null; }
}
return pigServer.get();
}
```

> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. 
>   Unable to check name hdfs://DC-001:9000/user/root
>   at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1607)
>   at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1546)
>   at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
>   at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:529)
>   at com.hugedata.cdnserver.datanalysis.CDNResolve2Hbase.execute(Unknown Source)
>   at com.hugedata.cdnserver.DatAnalysis.cdnResolve2Hbase(Unknown Source)
>   at com.hugedata.cdnserver.task.HandleDomainNameLogTask.execute(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
>   at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
>   at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
>   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
>   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
>
> Caused by: Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
>    pig script failed to validate:  org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://DC-001:9000/user/root
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
>   at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1599)
>
> ... 15 more
>   Caused by: 
>    pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://DC-001:9000/user/root
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:835)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3236)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1315)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
>
> ... 16 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://DC-001:9000/user/root
>   at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:207)
>   at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:128)
>   at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:138)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserUtils.getCurrentDir(QueryParserUtils.java:91)
>   at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:827)
>
> ... 22 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:264)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:873)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:513)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:768)
>   at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:200)
>
> > ... 26 more

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an `HDFSClient` issue. The problem as I understand is that the `FileSystem` object is cached. So my guess is that one Thread is closing it while another Thread is still using it. `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed at`

Take a look at this other SO post about multiple FileSystem instances. [Multiples Hadoop FileSystem instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421218/multiples-hadoop-filesystem-instances)

Comment: Pradeep, Thanks for your reply, I will try this out, in fact, I have a quesiton, should Pig 0.11.1 works in a multi-threaded program at all?  I have read some documents that it says it does not support in the past but not sure for now.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're getting suggests that you're not using the same hadoop client as in you're server.
can you check the hadoop version installed locally?