# Talend tPigLoad component issue

Tags: bigdata, talend

Quick question is had anyone ever get the tPigload component working with cloudera5 
I am using cloudera 5 
talend 5.4 and 5.5 
where ever there is a scope of map reduce talend is complaining.
Following is the error description:

```
Exception in component tPigLoad_1
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Unable to check name hdfs://txwlcloud2:8020/user/thor
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1608)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1547)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:518)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:531)
at bigdata.testpig_0_1.testpig.tPigLoad_1Process(testpig.java:348)
at bigdata.testpig_0_1.testpig.runJobInTOS(testpig.java:599)
at bigdata.testpig_0_1.testpig.main(testpig.java:458)
Caused by: Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 1, column 21> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://txwlcloud2:8020/user/thor
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1600)
... 6 more
Caused by: 
<line 1, column 21> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://txwlcloud2:8020/user/thor
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:835)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3236)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1315)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://txwlcloud2:8020/user/thor
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:207)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:128)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:138)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserUtils.getCurrentDir(QueryParserUtils.java:91)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:827)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "TXWLHPW295/10.215.206.241"; destination host is: "txwlcloud2":8020;
```

[image: tpigload configuration]

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330860/apache-pig-error-6007-unable-to-check-name-message) not help?

Comment: As per the post "The errors you're getting suggests that you're not using the same hadoop client as in you're server. can you check the hadoop version installed locally?". This leads to few questions    A) Why do I have to install hadoop in my local machine (a windows box where talend is installed)?                                        B) My hadoop cluster is in the ubuntu nodes ? From beginning i was thinking there is some configuration issues coz tHiveload tPigload whatever needs mapreduce no working....

Comment: You can execute the MapReduce job directly on a remote Hadoop cluster. The answers there are suggesting that the driver versions/distribution versions that you're using in your Talend job may not be the same as what is running on your Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Thanks  ydaetskcoR. so my client machine(Talend) is windows there is no Hadoop installed. The cloudera cluster is virtual  box with ubuntu. So who do I make sure the "driver versions/distribution versions" are same?

Comment: If you haven't done so, explicitly import the hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u1-core.jar library using Talend's tLibraryLoad component.