# fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache causes SparkSQL slowness

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

This question is related to [Hive/Hadoop intermittent failure: Unable to move source to destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592337/hive-hadoop-intermittent-failure-unable-to-move-source-to-destination)

We found that we could avoid the problem of "Unable to move source ... Filesystem closed" by setting `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache` to `true`.

However, we also observed that the SparkSQL queries became very slow -- queries that used to finish within a few seconds now take more than 30 to 40 seconds to finish (even when the query is very simple, like reading a tiny table).

Is this normal?

My understanding of `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache` being true means that `FileSystem#get()` would always `createFileSystem()` instead of returning a cached `FileSystem`.  This setting prevents a `FileSystem` object from being shared by multiple clients and it really makes sense, because it would prevent, for example, two callers of `FileSystem#get()` from closing each other's filesystem.

(For example, see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422138/1168041) )

This setting would slow things down, but probably not by so much.

From: [hadoop-source-reading](https://github.com/sh0tt/hadoop-source-reading/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java)

```
/**
 * Returns the FileSystem for this URI's scheme and authority. The scheme of
 * the URI determines a configuration property name,
 * <tt>fs.<i>scheme</i>.class</tt> whose value names the FileSystem class.
 * The entire URI is passed to the FileSystem instance's initialize method.
 */
public static FileSystem get(URI uri, Configuration conf)
        throws IOException {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String authority = uri.getAuthority();

    if (scheme == null) { // no scheme: use default FS
        return get(conf);
    }

    if (authority == null) { // no authority
        URI defaultUri = getDefaultUri(conf);
        if (scheme.equals(defaultUri.getScheme()) // if scheme matches
                // default
                && defaultUri.getAuthority() != null) { // & default has
            // authority
            return get(defaultUri, conf); // return default
        }
    }

    String disableCacheName = String.format("fs.%s.impl.disable.cache",
            scheme);
    if (conf.getBoolean(disableCacheName, false)) {
        return createFileSystem(uri, conf);
    }

    return CACHE.get(uri, conf);
}
```

Would the slowness point to some other networking issues, such as resolving domain names?  Any insights to this problem are welcome.